# Inline list-style-type with dash

Tags: html, css

I need to write Inline list-style-type with dash.

this works:

```
'<ul><li style="list-style-type: '-' "> text </li></ul>'
```

But I use XtraReport and there it doesnt. There has to be quotation mark ' at the begining and at the end.

I edited the question.

Comment: `<ul>
  <li style="list-style-type: '- '"> text </ul>
</li>`

Comment: see my answe tested above code below

Answer (score 1):

Use ' for inside the inline, to avoid confusion to closing style property.

Also, close `<li>` tag first before closing `<ul>` tag.

So, instead of:

```
<ul><li style="list-style-type: "- ";"> text </ul></li>
```

use:

```
<ul><li style="list-style-type: '- ';"> text </li></ul>
```

Comment: I edited the question, unfortunately this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Check this code in a sandbox like codepen and you see it works. If it doesn't work for you, provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: ok, thank you, I use XtraReport and there it does not work.. There has to be quotation mark ' at the begining and at the end.

Answer (score 0):

– Item 1
  
  
    – Item 2
  
  
    – Item 3

```
"<ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;">
  <li style="display: inline; list-style-type: none;">
    <span>&ndash; Item 1</span><br>
  </li>
  <li style="display: inline; list-style-type: none;">
    <span>&ndash; Item 2</span><br>
  </li>
  <li style="display: inline; list-style-type: none;">
    <span>&ndash; Item 3</span><br>
  </li>
</ul>
"
```

added the style attribute to the  element to remove the default bullet points by setting list-style-type: none and added some additional styling to remove any default padding using padding

Each list item "(

)" has the display: inline property to make them appear inline, and the `list-style-type:` none property is set to remove any default `list-style-type.`

Inside each list item, the `"&ndash; HTML entity"` is used to represent the dash character.

Comment: I edited the question, unfortunately this solution doesn't work.

Comment: see updated answer code + demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it is working.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul.dash-list {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
ul.dash-list li::before {
    content: "-";
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<ul class="dash-list">
  <li>First item </li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).